# Hide floor behind environment in ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm making an app (with ARKit) where I would like to change my floor color.
In this app I just overlay my floor with a color on the plane.
Now I'm already able to hide the plane on the floor if the table has been detected as a plane. But it doesn't disappear after the table leggs.

Is there any possibility to hide the floor after table leggs, sofa, chairs ...?

Answer (score 0):

No, what you describe is [mixed reality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_reality) opposed to augmented reality. In augmented reality all the virtual objects are overlays on reality, regardless of whether those objects are 3D or 2D objects. In mixed reality virtual objects can be behind/below physical objects in reality.